# Condensing rows with CTE and cases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble trying to group/condense the results from this query properly.

Here's what I want the results to be:

```
Person ID | Plan ID 1 | Plan ID 2 | Plan ID 3
   1         A            B           C
   2         A            B           NULL
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
Person ID | Plan ID 1 | Plan ID 2 | Plan ID 3
    1        A            NULL        NULL
    1        NULL         B           NULL
    1        NULL         NULL        C
    2        A            NULL        NULL
    2        NULL         B           NULL
    2        NULL         NULL        NULL
```

I thought of maybe trying to use two CTEs but couldn't get it to work out properly.

Here's the SQL:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        p.id [Person ID], plan.id [Plan ID],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.p_id ORDER BY plan.year DESC) [PlanRow],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.p_id ORDER BY a.close_date DESC) [AcctRow],
        a.close_date [Most Recent Close Date]
    FROM
        person p
    JOIN
        Account a ON p.id = a.p_id
    JOIN
        plan plan ON a.plan_id = plan.id
)
SELECT
    cte.[Person ID],
    CASE 
       WHEN cte.PlanRow = 1 THEN cte.[Plan ID] 
    END [Plan ID 1],
    CASE 
       WHEN cte.PlanRow = 2 THEN cte.[Plan ID] 
    END [Plan ID 2],
    CASE 
       WHEN cte.PlanRow = 3 THEN cte.[Plan ID] 
    END [Plan ID 3],
    CASE 
       WHEN cte.[AcctRow] = 1 THEN cte.[Most Recent Term Date] 
    END [Term Date]
FROM
    cte
```

I've tried to get rid of unnecessary columns in the select statement and renamed some things but the idea is there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `group by Person ID` and display the `MAX`

Comment: Your SQL will not work because `cte` is not in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need aggregation:

```
select cte.[Person ID],
       max(case when cte.PlanRow = 1 then cte.[Plan ID] end) as [Plan ID 1],
       max(case when cte.PlanRow = 2 then cte.[Plan ID] end) as [Plan ID 2],
       max(case when cte.PlanRow = 3 then cte.[Plan ID] end) as [Plan ID 3],
       max(case when cte.[FlexRow]=1 then cte.[Most Recent Term Date] end) as [Term Date]
from cte
group by cte.[Person ID];
```

Comment: So obvious, ha. I guess I figured there'd be a more "correct" way to do it since I don't actually need a max. Thank you!

Comment: @user3007447 . . . The max of one value is simply the value.  The `max()` is there to return the value from the row with a value in that column.